# Use selected branch on github workflow

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, workflow, cicd

I want to have the value of the selected branch on the GitHub workflow run; I know that I can define another input for the branch and read it, but I don't want to do that; I want to read the selected branch.

[image]

Something like this?!

```yaml
name: Get selected branch
run-name: "Running on @${{ inputs.SELECTED_BRACNH }}"
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the name of the GitHub Branch in the workflow it's not needed an input, you can use the [Default environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables).

Specifically for the branch name you can use

- `GITHUB_REF`, The fully-formed ref of the branch or tag that triggered the workflow run.
- `GITHUB_REF_NAME`, The short ref name of the branch or tag that triggered the workflow run.

Comment: If you want to have multiple version of the workflow it's correct, but very often you want to have a single version of the workflow that runs the same action against different branches and avoid rebasing all branches every single time you modify it :) then input comes in handy

Comment: Probably I misunderstood the question, sorry

Answer (score 0):

To run a workflow on a different branch using this selector, you have to add workflow to that branch - or simply rebase it on top of the `master` branch.

Keep in mind that it will then use a version that is in that branch always. If you modify it on `master` you need to rebase or merge changes to all branches.

Sometimes it's desired, but if you want to always run a version that is on `master`, but checkout a different branch you need to use custom `input` in your workflow.

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      branch:
        description: 'Branch to checkout'
```

And then:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    ref: ${{ inputs.branch }}
```

Comment: No, I don't want to use this way; it will add another input to run the workflow popup, I want to access the selected branch from that select branch field

Comment: @SayJeyHi then you have to merge workflow into that branch as in my answer at the start